# How to connect to remote mongodb running on my raspberrypi with my Spring application?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am just using the mongodb for first time, and also beginner in spring framework. I have a raspberry pi with mongodb running, and I want to connect to it with my Spring application. Spring application now runs well with locally hosted mongodb.

Raspberry pi needs authentication while connecting via ssh. How can I specify all the required parameters on spring application to correctly connect to remote mongodb database. This has been bugging me whole day. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you wouldnt connect over ssh, just open the mongo port on your pi, and then update the config in your spring app to point toit

Answer (score 0):

if you go to the `mongod.conf` file there is a setting `net.bindIp`

It should say `127.0.0.1` by default - set it to `0.0.0.0` this will make it accessible - then get the IP of the PI and configure spring to point to it.

[Here's the mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net-options)